# Issue adding a callback for a surfaceview - Android

Tags: android

I am having difficulty adding a `callback` during a button click:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......

//get the Image View at the main.xml file
setIv_image((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gimg1));

//get the Surface View at the main.xml file
setSv((SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.testin));

//Get a surface
setsHolder(getSv().getHolder());

// SET CALLBACK
setCalling((Callback) this);
.......
takeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                        //add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View callbacks
                    getsHolder().addCallback(getCalling());
                        //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
                    getsHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            } 
        });
.....My functions to work for the surfaceview
```

Now this works perfectly is I simply remove the `getsHolder().addCallback(getCalling());` and move it above outside of the `setOnClickListener...`

My issue is I want it to work when my button is clicked, but it does not work properly if I have it inside the click event.

Thoughts suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Call `getsHolder()` using `this` as follows...

```
    takeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View callbacks
            this.getsHolder().addCallback(getCalling());

            //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
            this.getsHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        } 
    });
```